# Flutter retrieve data from input component

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am using my own input component. I want to acces input value from another component. I can pass some values (like; hint text, color) but i can not retrive input value. I searched to much but i can not find anything.

i can do this:

```
inputComponent("your name",Colors.red);
```

i want to do this:

```
inputComponent("your name",Colors.red, onChangeFunc({
String inputValue = inputComponent.getValue(); // like this
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found the answer.
You can write onChange event from another component and you can use this in your custom component. But pay attention, don't use onChanged and TextEditingController. Just use onChanged func.

```
CustomInputComponent(onChanged1: (val) {print("value: $val");}
```